# Update Multiple ID's based on field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to find all lines of data that have a value, say 'N/A'

I want to then update ALL the lines of data where they have the same CommonID into the NewDataHere Column so in the example below ID 1 and 2 would be affected

I am doing this in a stored procedure

**Code for far:**

```
DECLARE @sqlPRatingChange NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlPRatingChange = 'UPDATE TblAsbestos SET  NewDataHere= ''NA''  
WHERE (SELECT ID FROM TBLASBESTOS WHERE VALUE= ''N/A'')'''
EXEC (@sqlPRatingChange)
```

**Example of Database as it should look after code**

- ID-VALUE-NewDataHere

  1-N/A-N/A

  2-C-N/A

  2-N/A-N/A

  1-A-N/A

  3-B-''

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using dynamic SQL?  Your query seems close enough.  It just needs a correlation clause:

```
UPDATE TblAsbestos
    SET  NewDataHere = 'NA'
    WHERE (SELECT ID FROM TBLASBESTOS a2 WHERE VALUE = 'N/A' AND TblAsbestos.id = a2.id);
```

In SQL Server, I might be inclined to do this using a CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*,
             sum(case when value = 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as numNAs
      from TblAsbestos a
     )
update toupdate
    set NewDataHere = 'NA'
    where numNAs > 0;
```

Comment: Now you say that, no idea! Over complicating things! I get error: Incorrect syntax near 'a'. from your code (first one)

Answer (score 2):

This should possibly be a comment on Gordon's answer, but it got too long and the formatting that an answer affords helps...

The incorrect syntax error is because in SQL Server you cannot alias the target of an update statement (not to be confused with using an alias as the target which is allowed). The where clause is also incorrect, it appears to be mix between an `EXISTS` clause and an `IN` clause, but has ended up as neither. I think you need:

```
UPDATE  TblAsbestos
SET     NewDataHere = 'NA'
WHERE   EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    TblAsbestos AS a 
            WHERE   a.Value = 'N/A' 
            AND     a.id = TblAsbestos.id
        );
```

Or

```
UPDATE  TblAsbestos
SET     NewDataHere = 'NA'
WHERE   ID IN (SELECT a.ID FROM TblAsbestos AS a WHERE a.Value = 'N/A');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just replace table1 with your table name :

```
update a
set NewDataHere = 'N/A'
from table1 as a
where exists(select 1 from table1 as b where a.id = b.id and b.value = 'N/A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TblAsbestos a
   SET  NewDataHere = 'NA'
 WHERE Exists (SELECT Top 1 ID 
                 FROM TBLASBESTOS a2 
                WHERE Upper(value) = 'N/A' 
                  AND a.id = a2.id);
```